# How can you manually find the Java Development Kit when setting up Android Studio on a PC running Windows 8.1?

Tags: java, android, java-7

I visited the link that is shown by Android Studio. But they did not have that exact version of the JDK. I installed what I could find for Windows. I thought I picked the correct file but still getting an error. What am I missing here?

This is a screenshot of what I tried

[image: Android Studio Setup]

Comment: You did not download the SDK from oracle's site?

Comment: I got this error because I tried to install Android Studio on this new computer before installing the JDK. What I ended up doing was install JDK8 and then restarted the computer. 

When I attempted to install Android Studio the second time, it worked just fine without asking me to specify a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think possibly happened here is that your Path is not appropriately specified in Environment variables.
Follow the steps and your problem should be fixed:

1. Cancel the installation (For now)
2. Open up the Control Panel
3. Go to the "System and Security section"
4. Click on "System"
5. On the top left corner, it should say something like "Advanced System Settings". Open that up, and type in a password if necessary.
6. Under the "Advanced" tab, click "Environment Variables"
7. Under the "System Variables" section, scroll down until you find a variable called "Path"
8. Select it, and click the edit button.
9. DO NOT delete or touch anything here yet, but instead try to find a location that says something like: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin;"
10. If you do find that, ONLY EDIT the "jdk1.7.0_40" to what your current JDK is. For example, if I had the same JDK as you, 1.7.0_79, the location would be changed to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;"
11. Save and exit out of all the windows we opened.
12. Restart your installer, and it should work!

Good Luck!